# Every non-trivial finite solvable group has a normal subgroup of prime index

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a non-trivial finite solvable group.Then $G$ has a normal subgroup of prime index.

I use the below fact to solve the problem.

"Every finite solvable group has a composition series that every factor of the series is cyclic of prime order."

I wonder if there is any other way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: choose a maximal normal subgroup $M$. Then $G/M$ is simple and is solvable, hence cyclic of prime order.

Comment: Thank you but maybe it doesn't have  a maximal subgroup which is normal.

Comment: You are mixing up two things: there is a difference between *normal maximal* and *maximal normal*. If $M$ is maximal normal then there is no normal proper subgroup that contains $M$ properly. These groups always exist in finite groups (and $M$ could be trivial). Of course, not every maximal subgroup is normal (in nilpotent groups this is the case and is equivalent to nilpotency) an example being $S_3$ with subgroups of order $2$.

Comment: I understand,thank you.